# How to create or replace a edge

Tags: arangodb

In ArangoDB, I'have a graph with two Vertexs(Users and Devices) one Edge(User Device Relation).
With one User and one Device there can only be one Relation, so the Edge's key is fixed like "{User Key}_{Device Key}". My questions are:

- Is there a single command can create a new edge if not exist and replace one if already exist?
- With Java driver,  what is the equal method of "collection.exists(document)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a single command can create a new edge if not exist and
>   replace one if already exist?

No unfortunately not, you would first have to look up the edge and update/create if needed.

> With Java driver, what is the equal method of
>   "collection.exists(document)"?

Which Java driver are you using ? If you are using [this](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver) one (the one we recommend)
you could use

> checkDocument

but you have to surround it with a try catch and check if you receive a 404 error code :

```
try {
      driver.checkDocument(collectionName, documentKey);
      fail();
    } catch (ArangoException e) {
      assertThat(e.getCode(), is(0));
      assertThat(e.getErrorNumber(), is(404));
    }
```

Comment: it's not **documentHandle**, it's **documentKey**